# Как развернуть сайт локально с бэком на Ruby?

Tags: reactjs, сервер, ruby, localhost

Получил сайт состоящий из фронта на React и бэка на Ruby.
Фронт развернуть вроде как получилось, открывается на localhost:3000, но выдает ошибку 500. Получается нужно как-то настроить локальную среду.
Сталкиваюсь с таким впервые, пытаюсь разобраться.

Понимаю, что нужно для начала установить Ruby через терминал, но что дальше?
Необходимо также накатить базу данных (так понимаю в папке db)?
Как будут связаны фронт и бэк? (на самом сайте админка на поддомене)

Подскажите, какие команды прописать в терминал, куда копать? Прилагаю скрины содержимого папки с фронтом и папки с бэком.

*Фронт:*

[image: Фронт]

*Бэк:*

[image: Бэк]

**Update:**

Добавляю скрины терминала после команды "npm run start" и ошибок в консоли браузера. Замечу, что страница с ошибкой 500 открывается стилизованной, значит стили фронта и шаблон страницы он видит.

*Терминал:*

[image: Терминал 1]
[image: Терминал 2]

*Браузер:*

[image: Ошибки в браузере]

Comment: Там rubyonrails? В той 500 ошибке не было каких либо подробностей? У сервера открыта консоль при его запуске (там, думаю, можно увидеть логи)?

Comment: @gil9red спасибо за ответ! Вроде как просто ruby, но могу ошибаться, тк не сталкивался, если понять, на что обратить внимание, то скажу.. Насчет ошибок, в консоли браузера выдает "[Error] XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://localhost/settings due to access control checks." и "[Error] XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://localhost/main?offset=0&limit=6 due to access control checks."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Файле readme.md ничего полезного не содержит?

---

Сначала давайте поймем, что за зверь под капотом. Скорее всего в бэкенде использовался какой-то какой-то фреймворк, нужно понять какой именно. Под Ruby их [не так много](https://awesome-ruby.com/#-web-frameworks), поэтому задача не особенно сложная.

По скриншотам непонятно, что именно (скорее всего это Ruby On Rails), поэтому ответ может дать содержимое файла Gemfile — конфиг менеджера пакетов [Bundler](https://bundler.io/). В нем содержится перечень внешних устанавливаемых модулей (аналог package.json), которые в экосистеме Ruby называются Gem (гемы).

Внутри Gemfile вы обнаружите примерно такое содержание:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 6.0.0'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg', '~> 0.18'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
```

Модули указываются c префиксом `gem`, то есть строка `gem 'rails', '~> 6.0.0'` означает, что в приложении используется гем `rails` (фреймворк Ruby On Rails) версии 6.0.*, где * — любая цифра минорной версии.

В файле Gemfile вам нужно найти совпадение названия фреймворка ([список вариантов](https://awesome-ruby.com/#-web-frameworks)) и одного из гемов. Учитывайте, что название гема и название фреймворка может различаться, но обычно название гема присутствует в названии фреймворка.

Как только нашли совпадение идете на сайт фреймворка (или репозиторий в Github) и ищете раздел, описывающий запуск. Будем надеяться, что разработчик придерживался общепринятых практик и вам не придется разбираться в изменениях в бутстрапе.

С фреймворком разобрались, теперь нужно выяснить, какая база данных используется. Возвращаетесь к Gemfile и ищете [драйвер к базе данных](https://awesome-ruby.com/#-database-drivers) аналогично тому, как вы искали фреймворк. Скорее всего это будет PostgreSQL, но лучше убедиться в этом.

Окей, давайте засетапим окружение, в котором бэкенд должен жить:

> Пояснение: я много лет не работал под Windows и не знаю, как сейчас дружит Ruby и Windows (раньше было плохо), поэтому можете попробовать https://rubyinstaller.org

Вам нужно установить:

1. Менеджер версий Ruby [RVM](https://rvm.io) и через него установить Ruby последней стабильной версии.
2. Менеджер пакетов [Bundler](https://bundler.io/)
3. Базу данных

Cетапим приложение: в консоли заходите в директорию с Gemfile и запускаете команду `bundle install`, это установит все необходимые модули.

И вот тут начинается самое сложное, в зависимости от фреймворка по инструкции на его сайте нужно:

1. Создать базу данных
2. Наполнить ее тестовыми данными
3. Запустить тесты (если они есть)
4. И запустить приложение
5. В соседней вкладке сбилдить и запустить фронт
6. Все должно работать

По дороге у вас что-то не получится, но что именно заранее угадать нельзя, поэтому приходите в комментарии, разберемся.

Comment: Огромное СПАСИБО за ответ! Безусловно помог разобраться, то что я искал! Тебе стоит написать статью об этом, так как подобной простой и понятной статьи я так и не нашел :)

Comment: Пожалуйста! Да не, какая статья... Их уже сотни, но они все для обучения с массой деталей, а у тебя редкий кейс «быстро запустить черный ящик».

Comment: Верно, но вот как раз для таких кейсов было бы очень полезно) Надеюсь люди с подобной проблемой будут натыкаться на этот вопрос здесь)